# Ant xml: How to break the long value attribute for options

Tags: xml, tomcat, ant

I have this jvmarg for the tomcat.jmx
The options span multiple lines and I wanted to break those options one per line.
But that is not acceptable by ant. How do people write this xml with long value argument.

```
 <property name="tomcat.jvmarg.jmx" value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=${tomcat.jmxport}
             -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=${tomcat.jmxport} -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${tomcat.jmxkeystore} -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=${tomcat.jmxpass}"/>
```

I tried this and starting tomcat fails, because the newlines in the argument are a hindrance.

**Invalid**

```
            <property name="tomcat.jvmarg.jmx"
                      value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
                             -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=${tomcat.jmxport}
                             -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
                             -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
                             -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=${tomcat.jmxport}
                             -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
                                                                  />
```

Comment: How do you pass your `tomcat.jvmarg.jmx` to the java process ? Using `<jvmarg line="${tomcat.jvmarg.jmx}"/>` should work. Actually, defining property's value with or without line break is quite the same, except that some space may be replaced by tab chars if you define the value on multiple lines and indent them.

Answer (score 1):

Is `tomcat.jvmarg.jmx` given to a `<java>` task? If so, consider nesting `<jvmarg>` elements under `<java>`...

```
<java ...>
    <jvmarg value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=${tomcat.jmxport}"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=${tomcat.jmxport}"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=true"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${tomcat.jmxkeystore}"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=${tomcat.jmxpass}"/>
</java>
```

This provides a way to easily see all of the arguments while avoiding the newlines problem.